# If a thermodynamic cycle on a Pressure-Volume diagram has internal irreversibilities, what does the area enclosed by the cycle represent?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, reversibility, heat-engine

When a cycle is internally reversible, the area enclosed by its P-v or T-s diagram is the net work, but what about when the cycle is internally irreversible? Is it net useful work on the surroundings plus work wasted on irreversibilities such as friction?

Answer (score 1):

For both internally reversible and internally irreversible processes, the area enclosed in a plot of $P_{ext}$ vs V determines the work .  However, to do this for an internally irreversible process, you need to know $P_{ext}$ vs V (either specified or controlled).  For an internally reversible process, $P_{ext}$ is equal to the pressure at each thermodynamic equilibrium state of the system along the path of the process (i.e., determined from the equation of state).